# Play a youtube video bu using shockwave flash object and youtube api

Tags: c#, winforms, youtube-api

I built a software in winforms and I want to insert to my software 1 video guide. After a few tests I managed to run videos from YouTube with shockwave flash object and youtube api. My questions are:

1. Is there a difference between the two if I want to run only 1 public video (Without user authentication)?
2. Is it permitted under Google's ads (youtube ads) policies?

Comment: You don't need any authentication if it's public and there isn't any age restriction.

Comment: Thank you!!! Is it permitted to use shockwave flash object under Google's ads (youtube ads) policies?

Answer (score 0):

**1 -**

> Is there a difference between the two if I want to run only 1 public
>   video (Without user authentication)?

Don't really understand your question, this is public data so no need authentications

**2-**

> Is it permitted under Google's ads (youtube ads) policies?

No ! It's prohibited by the Terms of Service of YouTube

> modify, replace, interfere with or block advertisements placed by YouTube in the YouTube Data, YouTube audiovisual content, or the
>   YouTube player;

Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms